# Splitting results from an Excel report into 2 halves

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ive spent the day trying to use hlookup, vlookup, and index/match results to do this, but I havent made progress. Im far from knowledgeable on Excel use.

We have a program that exports data to an excel template. Im trying to satisfy a request to take the current report layout and evenly split the data into 2 sheets. The trick is that the data could be displayed in anywhere from 1 to 60 columns. The columns are always present but the cells may be empty. So for example, if the reports showed 29 results, then sheet 1 would show results 1-60, but only 1-29 will have data. This update should recognize the columns with data, and split the results between 2 sheets. So if sheet one has the original data, then sheet 2 would show results for columns 1-15 and sheet 3 would show results 16-29. Another report may have the full 60 so 30 results on sheet 2 and 30 on sheets 3.

I cannot change the layout for the way the report generates. The attached image for context is showing 10 results so it should be split into 2 5 result sections.

Thanks to whoever saves me the time of struggling through this more tomorrow!

[image: Sample image of report format]

Comment: Can you send an example with the three sheets? In the attached image, what is on lines 1-9?

Answer (score 0):

The required split can be achieved using some helper ranges and a formula with nested `OFFSET` functions.

First, some randomly generated example input data to work with...

[image: Randomly Generated Input Data]

The range for the data extends as far as cell `G70` and for convenience the range `B2:G70` is named `LineData`.

The shaded cell in the top-right corner (ie cell `A1`) has some significance. It acts as an "anchor cell" for defining the location of the input data. In the OP, the equivalent "anchor cell" is cell `A9`. As shown subsequently, the "anchor cell" is used as the first argument of the outermost `OFFSET` in the formulas used for the required outputs. Again for convenience, the "anchor cell" is named as `InputAnchor` (using the Name manager).

The input data comprises up to 60 ***line sets*** where each line set is a 5×1 range of worksheet cells. In the example data, the ranges `B3:B7`, `D10:D14` and `F24:F28` are all examples of line sets.

The number of line sets actually present in the input data is calculated using the formula

`=COUNT(LineData)/5`

and is named `Lines`. The number of line sets required in the first part of the output is calculated using

`=ROUNDUP(Lines/2,0)`

and is named `Lines1`. For the example data shown, `Lines` is 29 and `Lines1` is 15.

The next step is to construct the helper ranges. Each helper is a 5×6 range of worksheet cells.

The input data comprises up to 60 line sets organised into a 10×6 ***array of line sets***. Since the output comprises these same input line sets allocated "equally" between two output worksheets, it follows that the two outputs will  also be arranged into arrays of line sets, though of size 5×6 rather than 10×6.

The 5×6 structure of the helper ranges reflects the 5×6 structure of the two output arrays of line sets.

There are 4 helper ranges per output and the 8 ranges are shown below.

[image: Helper Ranges]

The helpers for the first output are on the left and for the second output are on the right. The formulas used in the helper ranges are provided in the Appendix. The helpers are explained next.

The input line sets are numbered in a row-wise fashion across their 10×6 array of line sets (reflecting the  number in the header of each "line set"). The two helpers labelled ITEM1 (range `J5:O9` in the picture) and ITEM2 (range `Q5:V9`) show the required positions for each of the input line sets in the two output arrays of line sets.

The example data shows there are 29 input line sets numbered from 1 to 29. The helper labelled ITEM1 show where the line sets numbered from 1 to 15 should appear in the first output array of line sets. The helper labelled ITEM2, similarly show where line sets 16 to 29 should appear in the second output array.

Values of zero within these two helpers mean the corresponding position in the output array of line sets should appear empty.

The two helpers labelled ROW (ranges `J11:O15` and `Q11:V15`) show for each input line set its row number within the 10×6 input array of line sets. The helpers labelled ROW1 (range `J17:O21`) and ROW2 (range `Q17:V21`) convert these array row numbers to worksheet rows as the row offset of the corresponding line set from the `InputAnchor`.

The helpers labelled `COL1` (range `J23:O27`) and `COL2` (range `Q23:V27`) similarly identify worksheet column numbers as the column offset from the `InputAnchor`.

In effect, the line set to be placed in the (*r*,*c*)'th position of the first output array of line sets will be located in the input worksheet at

`INDEX(Helpers!:J17:O21,r,c)` rows below the `InputAnchor` and
`INDEX(Helpers!J23:O27,r,c)` columns to its right

**Formula development**

The `INDEX` expressions above are used to derive formulas for use in the output worksheets.

The line set in the (*r*,*c*)'th position of the first output array of line sets can be referenced (in the output worksheet) using the formula:

`=OFFSET(InputAnchor,INDEX(Helpers!J21:O21,r,c),INDEX(Helpers!J23:O27,r,c),5,1)`

with a similar expression being used for the (*r*,*c*)'th position of the second output array of line sets.

The nested `OFFSET` arises by naming cells in the `Helper` worksheet.

The cell labelled ITEM1 (cell `I4`) is named `ITEM1_`.
The cell labelled ROW1 (cell `I10`) is named `ROW1_`.
The cell labelled COL1 (cell `I16`)is labelled `COL1_`.

The cells labelled ITEM2, ROW2 and COL2 are similarly named.

This allows the nested `INDEX` functions in the formula above to be replaced by `OFFSET` functions as follows:

`=OFFSET(InputAnchor,OFFSET(ROW1_,r,c),OFFSET(COL1_,r,c),5,1)`

Before this formula can be used in an output worksheet, it is necessary to determine the *r*,*c* values. Similar to the input worksheet, the two output worksheets can also be anchored relative to their own anchor cells - named as `Output1Anchor` and `Output2Anchor`, respectively.

In the first output worksheet the row number, *r*, of the 5×6 output array of line sets corresponding to any worksheet cell in an output line set is provided by

`1+INT((ROW()-ROW(Output1Anchor)-2)/7)`

and the column number, *c*, is provided by

`COLUMN()-COLUMN(Output1Anchor)`

In addition, output should be supressed whenever `OFFSET(ITEM1_,r,c)` equals zero. Replacing *r* and *c* with the two expressions above and introducing an `IF` for output suppression leads to the formula

```
=LET(
     r, 1 + INT((ROW() - ROW(Output1Anchor) - 2) / 7),
     c, COLUMN() - COLUMN(Output1Anchor),
     IF(
        OFFSET(ITEM1_, r, c, ) = 0,
        "",  
        OFFSET(
               InputAnchor,
               OFFSET(ROW1_, r, c),
               OFFSET(COL1_, r, c),
               5,
               1
              )
       )
    )
```

This formula has been applied to the following ranges of the first output worksheet shown below: `B4:G4`, `B11:G11`, `B18:G18`, `B25:G25` and `B32:G32`.

[image: First Output]

The corresponding formula for use in the second output is

```
=LET(
     r, 1 + INT(ROW() - ROW(Output2Anchor) - 2) / 7),
     c, COLUMN() - COLUMN(Output2Anchor),
     IF(
        OFFSET(ITEM2_, r, c, ) = 0,
        "",  
        OFFSET(
               InputAnchor,
               OFFSET(ROW2_, r, c),
               OFFSET(COL2_, r, c),
               5,
               1
              )
       )
    )
```

This formula has been applied to the following ranges of the second output worksheet shown below: `B3:G3`, `B10:G10`, `B17:G17`, `B24:G24` and `B31:G31`

[image: Second Output]

***Note*** The "anchor cells" of the first and second outputs are not identically positioned. This demonstrates the flexibility of using "anchor cells" rather than fixed worksheet locations.

**A note on requirements**

The two output formulas set out above require a version of Excel which supports dynamic arrays. There are two reasons for this:

1. the outermost `OFFSET` function in each formula spills its results to a 5×1 range output cells
2. use of the `LET` function in each formula

Both requirements can be worked around for versions of Excel which do not support dynamic arrays.

The first requires that instead of using an array formula to generate an output line set, a non-array formula should is used to generate each cell of the output line set.

Adapting the first nested `OFFSET` formula above, a formula for the *i*'th cell of the line set in position (*r*,*c*) of the output array can be written as

`=OFFSET(InputAnchor,OFFSET(ROW1_,r,c)+(i-1),OFFSET(COL1_,r,c))`

The `(i-1)` values can be represent on the first output sheet using the expression

`MOD(ROW()-ROW(Output1Anchor)-2,7)`

The second requirement for the `LET` function ccan be an be dealt with by replacing *r* and *c* with their corresponding expressions.

Dealing with both requirements leads to a formula applicable to each cell in an output line set as:

```
     =IF(
         OFFSET(
               ITEM1_,
               1 + INT((ROW() - ROW(Output1Anchor) - 2) / 7),
               COLUMN() - COLUMN(Output1Anchor), 
              ) = 0,
         "",  
         OFFSET(
               InputAnchor,
               OFFSET(
                      ROW1_,
                      1+INT((ROW() - ROW(Output1Anchor) - 2) / 7), 
                      COLUMN() - COLUMN(Output1Anchor)
                     ) + 
                      MOD(ROW()-ROW(Output1Anchor)-2,7),
               OFFSET(
                      COL1_,
                      1+INT((ROW() - ROW(Output1Anchor) - 2) / 7),
                      COLUMN() - COLUMN(Output1Anchor)
                     )
              )
        )
```

This formula can be inserted into cell `B4` of the first output worksheet and then copied to range `B4:G8`.Following this, range `B4:G8` is copied to ranges `B11:G15`, `B18:G22`, `B25:G29` and `B32:G36`.

An equivalent approach can similarly be adopted for the second output worksheet. The 7 occurrences of `Output1Anchor`  in the formula are replaced with `Output2Anchor`. The occurrences of `ITEM1_`, `ROW1_` and `COL1_` with `COL1_` are respectively replaced with `ITEM2_`, `ROW2_` and `COL2_`.

**Appendix**

The formulas used in the helper arrays are set out below. The helper arrays can be positioned anywhere in the workbook such as the input worksheet or a separate helper worksheet, etc. The formulas below should be adjusted to reflect the position actually used.

***1. Range `J5:O9`, labelled ITEM1***

Cell `J5`: Formula is `=IF(Lines1<1,0,1)`
Cell `K5`: Formula is `=IF(J5=0,0,IF(J5<Lines1,1+J5,0))`,copy to range `K5:O6`
Cell `J6`: Formula is `=IF(O5=0,0,IF(O5<Lines1,1+O5,0))`
Range `J7:O9`: Copy range `J6:O6` to range `J7:09`
Cell `I4`: Name as `ITEM1_` using the Name manager.

***2. Range `J11:O15`, labelled ROW*** (left side)

Cell `J11`: Formula is `=IF(J5=0,0,1+INT((J5-1)/6))`
Copy cell `J11` to range `J11:O15`

***3. Range `J17:O21`, labelled ROW1***

Cell `J17`: Formula is `=IF(J11=0,0,2+7*(J11-1))`
Copy cell `J17` to range `J17:O21`
Cell `I16`: Name as `ROW1_` using the Name manager.

***4. Range `J23:O27`, labelled COL1***

Cell `J23`: Formula is `=IF(J5=0,0,J$22)`
Copy cell `J23` to range `J23:O27`
Cell `I22`: Name as `COL1_` using the Name manager.

***5. Range `Q5:V9`, labelled ITEM2***

Cell `Q5`: Formula is `=IF(Lines<1+MAX(J5:O9),0,1+MAX(J5:O9))`
Cell `R5`: Formula is `=IF(Q5=0,0,IF(Q5<Lines1,1+Q5,0))`,copy to range `R5:V6`
Cell `Q6`: Formula is `=IF(V5=0,0,IF(V5<Lines1,1+V5,0))`
Range `Q7:V9`: Copy range `Q6:V6` to range `Q7:V9`
Cell `P4`: Name as `ITEM2_` using the Name manager.

***6. Range `Q11:V15`, labelled ROW*** (right side)

Cell `Q11`: Formula is `=IF(Q5=0,0,1+INT((Q5-1)/6))`
Copy cell `Q11` to range `Q11:V15`

***7. Range `Q17:V21`, labelled ROW2***

Cell `Q17`: Formula is `=IF(Q11=0,0,2+7*(Q11-1))`
Copy cell `Q17` to range `Q17:V21`
Cell `P16`: Name as `ROW2_` using the Name manager.

***8. Range `Q23:V27`, labelled COL2***

Cell `Q23`: Formula is `=LET(m,MAX(INDEX(J23:O27,MAX(J11:O15),)),IF(Q5=0,0,IF(m=6,1,1+m)))`
Cell `R23`: Formula is `=IF(R5=0,0,IF(Q23=6,1,1+Q23))`, copy to range `R23:V24`
Cell `Q24`: Formula is `=IF(Q6=0,0,IF(V23=6,1,1+V23))`
Range `Q25:V27`: Copy range `Q24:V24` to range `Q25:V27`
Cell `P22`: Name as `COL22_` using the Name manager.